# How to loop through all controls in a form, including controls in a subform - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I found this code on this site and, by description, it is exactly what I need (plus I'll need to expand it to subforms) but I can't get it to work. I tried it in the Form's VBA area and in a separate module. I also changed 'fmr As Form' to 'frm as Form_Submissions' to specify which form.

I have a command button with click event code 'Application.Run "colCtrlReq"' and the colCtrlReq code saved in a module. The 'frm As Form' prevents the code from being recognized/found so I get error 449/argument not optional.

I tried removing 'Option Compare Database' but nope. I tried removing 'frm As Form' from the sub name and adding 'Dim frm As Form' to the code but then get other errors. (I'm new to Access so grasping at straws.)

Other Errors:

-on acTextBox.Value I get a Compile error/invalid qualifier for acTextBox

-on For Each ctl In frm.Controls I get run-time error 91/object variable or with variable not set (probably cuz I removed 'frm As Form' from the name)

My goal is this:

-If it's a text box or combo box, required and blank = change background color

-If it's a check box or option button, required and false = change background color

Any help getting this to work and expanding it to subforms would be greatly appreciated!

Option Compare Database

```
Public Sub colCtrlReq(frm As Form)
'  Sets background color for required field -> Tag = *
Dim setColor As String
setColor = RGB(255, 244, 164)
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        'If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox And acTextBox.Value = "" And InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "*") <> 0 Then
            ctl.BackColor = setColor
        End If
Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, @noelmcg. Since you posted on the page where I found the original code I'm hoping you may be able to help me with this. Thanks if you can!

Comment: Hi, @David-W-Fenton. Since you posted on the page where I found the original code I'm hoping you may be able to help me with this. Thanks if you can!

Comment: Hi, @Fionnuala, Since you posted on the page where I found the original code I'm hoping you may be able to help me with this. Thanks if you can!

Comment: Hi, @Remou, Since you were mentioned on the page where I found the original code I'm hoping you may be able to help me with this. Thanks if you can!

Comment: Hi, @bonCodigo, Since you posted on the page where I found the original code I'm hoping you may be able to help me with this. Thanks if you can!

Comment: There's lots of reference topics out there already on referencing subforms. As for this sample code edit, you're best to use a SELECT CASE ctl.ControlType instead of a big IF statement. Contols have different properties and some don't have Value - so that'll generate errors. Just use the Case to filter out and handle your text boxes, combo boxes, checkboxes and options

Comment: Thanks, @dbmitch. I got a piece of the answer on another forum then managed to flesh it out on my own but still need to get it to loop through subforms. I'll post my answer for just the form and start looking for topics re subforms. If you know of a good one for my needs could you please post a link?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Validate()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim l As Control

setColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

foundrequired = 0

For Each ctrl In Form_Submissions.Controls

    If InStr(1, ctrl.Tag, "*") <> 0 Then

        If ctrl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctrl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            If Nz(ctrl.Value, vbNullString) = "" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = setColor
            foundrequired = foundrequired + 1
            Else
            ctrl.BackColor = 16777215
            End If
        End If

        If ctrl.ControlType = acCheckBox Or ctrl.ControlType = acOptionButton Then
            If Nz(ctrl.Value) = 0 Then
                For Each l In Form_Submissions.Controls
                    If l.ControlType = acLabel And Right(l.Name, 3) = Right(ctrl.Name, 3) Then
                    l.BackColor = setColor
                    foundrequired = foundrequired + 1
                    End If
                Next l
            Else
                For Each l In Form_Submissions.Controls
                    If l.ControlType = acLabel And Right(l.Name, 3) = Right(ctrl.Name, 3) Then
                    l.BackColor = 16777215
                    End If
                Next l
            End If
        End If

    End If

Next ctrl

If foundrequired > 0 Then
MsgBox "Please fill in the required fields before submitting.", vbCritical, "HOTEL CHECKS"
Exit Sub
End If

'continue code if passes validation

End Sub
```